# Add a column to existing entity in Azure Table Storage

Tags: azure-table-storage

I'm saving some transactional data in a table on Azure Table Storage. When I tried to "update" an existing entity in my table and add a new column to it, looks like it's not adding the column.

Here's an example: I'm saving time sheet entries in the table. When I first create the entity, there's a StartTime but no EndTime

```
PersonId -- TransactionId -- StartTime -- EndTime
```

So, when I first create the entity in the table, I end up with `PersonId, TransactionId and StartTime` columns. Later, I want to add the `EndTime` but looks like it's not adding it because in my object `EndTime` is a nullable property and when it's `NULL`, that column is not created.

Is there not a way to update an existing entity and add a column in the process? If not, I'll have to put some dummy date in the `EndTime` and store it during the initial creation of the entity so that the column is there and I can update it later.

I'd rather not store any dummy data though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is there not a way to update an existing entity and add a column in the process?

Yes, according to your case, we can do that with 2 ways: edit the transactional data model or using `DynamicTableEntity`

1.Edit the your transactional data model and set Endtime datetime and null value is accepted. Demo code as following,

```
 public class Transactional:TableEntity
    {
        public string PersonId { get; set; }
        public string TransactionId { get; set; }
        public DateTime StarTime { get; set; }
        public DateTime? EndTime { get; set; }

        public Transactional() { }

        // Define the PK and RK
        public Transactional(string persionId, string transactionId)
        {
            PartitionKey = persionId;
            RowKey = transactionId;
        }
    }
```

If we don't assign the value to and try to insert to entity to the table, then there is no EndTime column. The following is the demo code.

```
 CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CreateStorageAccountFromConnectionString(CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("StorageConnectionString"));
 var tableClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudTableClient();
 var table = tableClient.GetTableReference("tableName");
 table.CreateIfNotExists();
 var guid = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
 Transactional transactional = new Transactional("tomtest", guid);
 transactional.StarTime =DateTime.UtcNow;
 TableOperation insertOrMergeOperation =   TableOperation.InsertOrMerge(transactional);         
 TableResult result = table.Execute(insertOrMergeOperation);
```

How to update the entity

```
 // update entity
 TableOperation retrieveOperation = TableOperation.Retrieve<Transactional>("tomtest", "pk"); //PK, RK
 TableResult retrieveResult = table.Execute(retrieveOperation);
 Transactional updateEntity = retrieveResult.Result as Transactional;
 if (updateEntity != null) updateEntity.EndTime = DateTime.UtcNow;
 TableOperation insertOrMergeOperation = TableOperation.InsertOrMerge(updateEntity);
 // Execute the operation.
 TableResult resultinsertormerge = table.Execute(insertOrMergeOperation);
```

2.We could use `DynamicTableEntity` to  add a column in the process. The following is demo code.

```
  var entity = new DynamicTableEntity("tomtest", "pk"); //PK, RK
  entity.Properties.Add("EndTime", new EntityProperty(DateTime.UtcNow));      //properties want to add    
  var mergeOperation = TableOperation.InsertOrMerge(entity);
  table.Execute(mergeOperation);
```

Answer (score 2):

Azure Table Storage is a **schema-less** data base, which means entities within a table can have completely different columns actually.

In other words, you can create the entities without **EndTime** property if it's not needed, and added the property in the future by [MergeEntity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/fileservices/merge-entity) / [UpdateEntity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/fileservices/update-entity2) operations if **EndTime** becomes necessary later.